# Vacuum filtration: will Polymer elements interfere with the vacuum?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, aqueous-solution, filtering

I am doing an experiment with vacuum filtration, where a Nylon filter is used to create a membrane (marked in pink in the picture attached). When I use the membrane, it frequently breaks in the process of transferring the membrane (on the Nylon filter) to another location. So I thought to put the Nylon filter onto a rigid ring, so that I can move the entire ring (with Nylon filter and my own membrane on top) without introducing cracks into my membrane. I wanted to 3D print this disk using a polymer resin, but was unsure, whether the polymer would interfere with the vacuum filtration process in some ways, or whether it would be good to use. I marked up on the picture, where the polymer ring would go (between the glass beakers).

Here is the image I mentioned to show my setup

[image: experiment setup]

Comment: Keeping aside that there are different filter materials (nylon, PFTE, paper, glass/glasswool) and filter funnels (e.g., http://emsar-laboratory.ro/en/magazin/filters-filtration/filter-funnels-125-ml/), what are the media you intend to filter?  For example, some organic solvents actually may corrode a frame (similar to an example like https://3dprint.nih.gov/discover/3DPX-004082) if made from poly lactic acid.  A hint about your filtration: look for a vacuum hose, the tubing attached to the sucction flask on the photo is too flexible and consequently, will limit the efficieny of your device.

Comment: It depends on the solvent.  DMF can weaken some of these non-paper /non-glass fibre filters. Additionally,  the order of events of filtration can cause breakage.  Pulling vacuum prior to adding solvent is different to filling the funnel and then applying vacuum